# Python selenium: Как отключить вывод информации от chromedriver.exe в консоль?

Tags: python, selenium

Нужно полностью отключить вывод в консоль от `chromedriver.exe`.

Есть уже много подобных вопросов, но ни один из ответов не помог мне.
Я пробовал добавлять такие параметры:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
options.add_argument("--disable-crash-reporter")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--output=/dev/null")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```

Но вместо пустой консоли при запуске все равно получаю это:

```py
PythonCode.py:30: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
PythonCode.py:30: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54651/devtools/browser/be095b07-a924-4db1-8ccb-aa5612610fd5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python пробовали?

Comment: @Volkodaff, да, забыл отметить, тоже пробовал и тоже не помогает

Comment: Варнинги от питона - выполнить чего он хочет, а для лога драйвера попробовать добавить параметр в `driver.Chrome(...., service_log_path='nul')`. Для фф помогает, может и для хрома такое есть

Answer (score 1):

Добавь строку:

```
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

[Отключение вывода selenium DevTools в консоль](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/disable+DevTools+listening+on+ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1+python)

Comment: Все равно остаются логи в консоли